# how to do order_by in SimpleJpaRepository?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, persistence

I have this entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "clients")
public class Client
    extends AbstractEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid")
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true)
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "gender")
    private Gender gender;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "type")
    private ClientType type;

    // Getters and setters

}
```

In my DAO i am using SimpleJpaRepository, so i have this implementation:

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class ClientDAOImpl
    implements ClientDAO {

    private SimpleJpaRepository<Client, String> support;

    public ClientDAOImpl(SimpleJpaRepository<Client, String> support) {
        Assert.assertNotNull(support);
        this.support = support;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public synchronized Page<Client> findAll(PageRequest pageRequest) {
        Page<Client> clientpaginated = this.support.findAll(SpecImpl.asc(), pageRequest);
        return clientpaginated;
    }

}
```

The method findAll() does not accept both Pageable and Sort parameters, so i have to do the sort (order_by) by Specification implementation. But i do not know how to do that, could you give me some help? I tried this:

```
public class SpecImpl {

    public static Specification<Client> asc() {
        return new Specification<Client>() {
            @Override
            public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Client> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
                query.orderBy(cb.asc(root.get("name")));
                return root.in(query);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

The exception i am getting with this:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Parameter value [org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.CriteriaQueryImpl@18fb3364] did not match expected type [com.despegar.movies.persistence.entity.Client (n/a)]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.CriteriaQueryImpl@18fb3364] did not match expected type [com.despegar.movies.persistence.entity.Client (n/a)]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:381)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:216)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:417)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy64.findAll(Unknown Source)
    at com.example.movies.domain.service.client.impl.ClientServiceImpl.getClients(ClientServiceImpl.java:58)
    at com.example.movies.service.controller.ClientController.getClients(ClientController.java:50)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:777)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:706)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1086)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:659)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1558)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1515)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.CriteriaQueryImpl@18fb3364] did not match expected type [com.despegar.movies.persistence.entity.Client (n/a)]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.BaseQueryImpl.validateBinding(BaseQueryImpl.java:874)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.access$000(QueryImpl.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl$ParameterRegistrationImpl.bindValue(QueryImpl.java:248)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.BaseQueryImpl.setParameter(BaseQueryImpl.java:620)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractQueryImpl.setParameter(AbstractQueryImpl.java:180)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractQueryImpl.setParameter(AbstractQueryImpl.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.compile.CriteriaCompiler$1$1.bind(CriteriaCompiler.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.CriteriaQueryImpl$1.buildCompiledQuery(CriteriaQueryImpl.java:386)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.compile.CriteriaCompiler.compile(CriteriaCompiler.java:147)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:736)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:344)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy61.createQuery(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:291)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy61.createQuery(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.getQuery(SimpleJpaRepository.java:509)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.getQuery(SimpleJpaRepository.java:487)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:369)
    at com.despegar.movies.persistence.dao.client.impl.ClientDAOImpl.findAll(ClientDAOImpl.java:34)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    ... 55 common frames omitted
```

How could i do that Order_by ? And is it possible to make more than one Order_by? Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`findAll` does support a `Pageable` with a `Sort`.  You can do:

```
jpaRepository.findAll(new PageRequest(1, 100, new Sort("name")));
```

Or sort by multiple fields:

```
jpaRepository.findAll(new PageRequest(1, 100, new Sort("name", "date")));
```

Or use different sort directions:

```
jpaRepository.findAll(new PageRequest(1, 100, new Sort(new Sort.Order(Sort.Direction.ASC, "name"), new Sort.Order(Sort.Direction.DESC, "date"))));
```

Comment: Thank you! That is exactly what i need. I was complaining it so much. Regards

Comment: Do take a look at the `Sort` class.  It has multiple constructors for all sorts of use cases.